# How to get only queried array object from an array in mongo db with regex?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have my data saved in mongo db like this

```
  {
 "_id": "5eff4376e036e45de9dbc6df",
 "social_connections":{
     "friend":{
         "friends":[
            {
                "_id": "5eff42dee036e45de9dbc6d3",
                "user_name": "x",
                "name": "Viper King"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5eff40efe036e45de9dbc6c9",
                "user_name": "z",
                "name": "Brad Prasad Pitt"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5eff50337508da5ff40bf36e",
                "user_name": "test",
                "name": "Test"
            }

         ]
         
     },
     "followers":{
        "following":[
            {
                "_id": "5eff42dee036e45de9dbc6d3",
                "user_name": "x",
                "name": "Viper King"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5eff40efe036e45de9dbc6c9",
                "user_name": "z",
                "name": "Brad Prasad Pitt"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5eff50337508da5ff40bf36e",
                "user_name": "test",
                "name": "Test"
            }
        ]
     }
 }
 }
```

I want to make a mongo db query in which I would pass the _id of the document that is 5eff4376e036e45de9dbc6df and a regex that is 'Vi', now **I want all those array objects whose name contains 'Vi'**. My expected output is:-

```
  {
 "_id": "5eff4376e036e45de9dbc6df",
 "social_connections":{
     "friend":{
         "friends":[
            {
                "_id": "5eff42dee036e45de9dbc6d3",
                "user_name": "x",
                "name": "Viper King"
            }

         ]
         
     },
     "followers":{
        "following":[
            {
                "_id": "5eff42dee036e45de9dbc6d3",
                "user_name": "x",
                "name": "Viper King"
            }
        ]
     }
 }
 }
```

You can also make a query which only return _id of those whose name contains 'Vi'

Comment: Use regular dot notation for the query + https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/ to retrieve only the matching array elements.

Comment: I already used it not working

Comment: You want to regex search 'Vi' in both `friends` and `following.friends`? You need to user the aggregation pipe where you should first use the $unwind both the array objects and then regex match them and use `$regex` to match your string then user $project to get the required output.

Comment: can you help with code I have tried many things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get a new filtered array and [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) to apply your regular expression:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "social_connections.friend.friends": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$social_connections.friend.friends",
                    as: "friend",
                    cond: {
                        $regexMatch: { input: "$$friend.name", regex: "Vi" }
                    }
                }
            },
            "social_connections.followers.following": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$social_connections.followers.following",
                    as: "follower",
                    cond: {
                        $regexMatch: { input: "$$follower.name", regex: "Vi" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VE6o_8psfp9)